# SQL insert into suspended - Read uncommitted or split query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that contains two insert into queries. While running the sp I often see these two as being suspended. The sp has been tested on a test server with almost no traffic but now as we moved it on to the production server these suspended states have appeared with 1-2 deadlocks.

I assume that SQL Server creates table locks while running these queries but I don't know what is the preferred way to solve this? 
The insert into queries are moving 30000 records in one iteration into an other database. These are archive data, so queries coming from the normal production processes are nothing to do with the data being archived, they are 2-3 years old.

- Can I add WITH NOLOCK to the selects to avoid suspended states and deadlocks?
- Or should I set ISOLATION LEVEL to READ UNCOMMITTED? (these records are old, they won't change)
- What other options do I have? Cursors to run through the ids it has to archive one by one? (I tried not to use cursors until now.)

These are the two queries. @workitemids and @workstepids are table variables containing one int field.

```
insert into archive_****.archive.workitems
            select * from ****.dbo.WorkItems where ****.dbo.workitems.Id in (select Id from @workitemIds);

insert into archive_****.archive.worksteps([Id], [Timestamp], [Description], [WorkPlace_Id], [WorkItemState_Id], [UserId], [WorkItem_Id], [Technology_Id], [Failcodes_Id], [DrawingNo], [ManualData], [Deleted], [WorkItemState_Arrival_Id], Workstepdatas)
            select [Id], [Timestamp], [Description], [WorkPlace_Id], [WorkItemState_Id], [UserId], [WorkItem_Id], [Technology_Id], [Failcodes_Id], [DrawingNo], [ManualData], [Deleted], [WorkItemState_Arrival_Id],
                (select Fieldname Field, Value [Value], Unit [Unit] from ****.dbo.workstepdatas wsd
                    left join ****.dbo.technologydatafields tdf on tdf.Id = wsd.TechnologyDatafields_Id
                    where tdf.fieldname is not null and wsd.WorkStep_Id = ws.Id
                        and value NOT LIKE '%[' + CHAR(0)+ '-' +CHAR(31)+']%'  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
                    for xml auto,type)
            from ****.dbo.worksteps ws
            where ws.Id in (select Id from @workstepIds);
```

Comment: I think it's the nested query in your second `insert`.  Have you tried compiling that as a CTE and then joining it to the main insert statement?  Also they are table variables, not temp tables.

Comment: @TJB I haven't tried CTE, yet. I'll google it. Fixed table variables, thanks.

Comment: @TJB I've transformed the two subqueries into a CTE and used that below the insert into. Unfortunately this didn't help anything.

Comment: Just to confirm, you don't have any concurrent processes against the affected tables in production.  Also are there any proceeding transactions that have been opened.  

Can you edit your question with the CTE you attempted?

Comment: I've added an answer with what I was thinking, please test and advise.  If you can screenshot the query plan that would also be useful (of the one I just offered).

Comment: @TJB I do have concurrent transactions writing the worksteps and workstepdatas tables. There are new records constantly being added to these two tables while the archiving sp running and tries to move records into an other database from the beginning of the two tables. I just have noticed that one of the fields I use in a join does not have an index on it. (Workstepdatas.Technologydatafields_id) I have added the new index but couldn't tested it yet. Do you think that this made the select so much slower that this can be a solution?

Comment: @TJB I'm trying your solution but I have limited time for testing on the production database where the problem occurs.

Comment: I've added some (With tablock) statements to the script too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please attempt to write the nested query into a cte as below and advise if any progress. You will need to change the database names.

```
insert into archive_db.archive.workitems (with tablock)
select *
from db.dbo.WorkItems as w
inner join @workitemIds as wi
    on w.Id = wi.id;

with xmlcte
    (ID, xmlRow)
as (
       select ws.id
            , (
                  select Fieldname as Field                           
                       , [Value]
                       , Unit
                  from db.dbo.workstepdatas wsd
                  left join db.dbo.technologydatafields tdf
                      on tdf.Id = wsd.TechnologyDatafields_Id
                  where
                      tdf.fieldname is not null
                      and wsd.WorkStep_Id = ws.Id
                      and [value] not like '%[' + char(0) + '-' + char(31) + ']%' collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2
                  for xml auto, type
              ) as xmlRow
       from db.dbo.worksteps as ws
   )
insert into archive_db.archive.worksteps (with tablock)
     (
         [Id]
       , [Timestamp]
       , [Description]
       , [WorkPlace_Id]
       , [WorkItemState_Id]
       , [UserId]
       , [WorkItem_Id]
       , [Technology_Id]
       , [Failcodes_Id]
       , [DrawingNo]
       , [ManualData]
       , [Deleted]
       , [WorkItemState_Arrival_Id]
       , Workstepdatas
     )
select ws.[Id]
     , [Timestamp]
     , [Description]
     , [WorkPlace_Id]
     , [WorkItemState_Id]
     , [UserId]
     , [WorkItem_Id]
     , [Technology_Id]
     , [Failcodes_Id]
     , [DrawingNo]
     , [ManualData]
     , [Deleted]
     , [WorkItemState_Arrival_Id]
     , [xmlRow]
from db.dbo.worksteps ws
inner join @workstepIds as wsi
    on ws.Id = wsi.id
inner join xmlcte -- I assume inner join is OK
    on ws.id = xmlcte.id;
```

Comment: Running these queries takes as much time as the original ones but doesn't hold the whole database. Other processes run flawlessly while these are running. Why did the original query blocked other processes and why this doesn't? Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Due to logical query processing.  The logical query processing order goes from>where>group by > having > select > order by.  You were attempting to select from `dbo.worksteps` where a row was in `dbo.worksteps` in your subquery.  You were doing both of these concurrently at the `from` stage and the nested query caused a deadlock.  In my solution, I created a relational construct through the cte to join on to `dbo.worksteps` after the `from` stage in the logical processing.